# Charges to enable more instance limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

Is there any charges to increase instance limit?

Example: 
For my AWS account in us-west-2 region I have instance limit 10 for p2.xlarge, if I want to have this instance limit to 20.

I only know that, probably I need to send support request to AWS Team to increase this limit. I just wondering is there any extra charges need to pay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no charge to increase the limit, as you mentioned, simply send a request to AWS support. Note however, that will still incur usage charges for any resources you use up to your new limit.